# Calculating rolling rates and excluding null rows

Tags: r

I have a dataset with ~40 variables with rows for each of the 25 areas and quarters, we have data from 2019 Q1 to today, 2022 Q2. For each quarter I am creating a rate (variable/population*10000) to allow comparison, however, we want each quarters rate to be based on the preceding 4 quarters i.e. 2022 Q2 rate will be the sum of the variable for 2022 Q2, Q1, 2021 Q4 and Q3. I can calculate this for all the relevant columns using the below

```
full_data_rates_pop %>%
  group_by(Area) %>%
  summarise(across(4:21, ~(sum(., na.rm = T))/(mean(Population_17.24))*10000)) %>%
  bind_rows(full_data_rates_pop) %>%
  arrange(Area,-Quarter)%>% # sort so that total rows come after the quarters
  mutate(Timeframe=if_else(is.na(Quarter),timeframe_value, 'Quarterly'))
```

This does the job for my areas however I also want to create regional rates for each time period, originally I just summed up the variable and population for all the areas and created the rates in the same way. However, I have realised that for some areas/time periods data is missing and as such the current method produces inaccurate results. I want for each column to be able to exclude any rows which are `Null`.

| Area | Quarter | Metric_1 | Metric_2 | Population |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022.2 | 45 | 89 | 12000 |
| A | 2022.1 | 58 | 23 | 12000 |
| A | 2021.4 | NULL | 64 | 11000 |
| A | 2021.3 | 20 | 76 | 11000 |
| B | 2022.2 | 56 | 101 | 9700 |
| B | 2022.1 | 32 | 78 | 9700 |
| B | 2021.4 | 41 | NULL | 10100 |
| B | 2021.3 | 38 | NULL | 10100 |

This is a mini dummy version of my data just with the latest 4 quarters but I want the new row to calculate so that the values are the sum of all values and the sum of population excluding any rows where the metric value was null

| Area | Quarter | Metric_1_rate | Metric_2_rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ALL | 2022.2 | 38.87 | 75.08 |

Is there a way to filter out any rows which have a null value for that column however it will still be needed for other rows where there is no null value?

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and in particular use dput to show the inputs so that it is reproducible.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here rather than a table so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg